# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int\log\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)\;\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried to solve this and have solved it. But I can't.

$$\int\log\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)\;\mathrm dx $$

I got this answer $$ \log\left(\tan^{-1}(x)\right)\cdot x. $$ But its wrong. Please help me someone.

Comment: Why do you (think you) need to find this? [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+log%28arctan%28x%29%29) can't do it.

Comment: @fug, I don't think that works. $u=\arctan x$, $x=\tan u$, $dx=\sec^2u\,du$, $\int\log u\sec^2u\,du$, integration by parts leads to $\int u^{-1}\tan u\,du$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You're right; also happened to delete my comment before yours appeared so apologies for messing up comment continuity.

Comment: @fuglede, no worries, I was about ready to post it as an example of something that wouldn't work when you made your comment, so I think it's good that it stays as a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the substitution $\tan(u)=x$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int\log(\tan^{-1}(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\log(u)\,\mathrm{d}\tan(u)\\
&=\log(u)\tan(u)-\int\frac{\tan(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$
However, I do not believe that $\frac{\tan(u)}{u}$ has an elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: What is elementary anti derivative? Does it means anti derivative which can't be expressed using normal functions. Right ?

Comment: Right. [**anti-derivative**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) is another name for integral, focusing on the idea that differentiation and integration are essentially inverse operations. [**elementary functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) are combinations of basic operations such as addition, multiplication, exponentiation, and logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

$ \int \log(\tan^{-1}(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$ Let $\tan^{-1}(x) = t \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}t $ .....(i)

Also x =\tan(t) .......(ii)

Therefore ( by using (ii)):
$$
\begin{align}
\int\log(\tan^{-1}(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&= \int\log(t) . (1+\tan^2(t))\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int (\log(t) + \log(t) \tan^2(t))dt\\
&= \int( \log(t) + \log(t) \sec^2(t) - \log(t) )\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&= \int \log(t) \sec^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}t 
\end{align}
$$
Which by using integration by parts can easily be solved  and using (ILATE ) which means take Inverse function, L-logarithmic function, A-algebric functin, T- Trigonometric function, E - exponential function .

Which can be written as :
$$
\log(t) \int \sec^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}t -\int \frac{1}{t}\tan(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
= \log(t)\tan(t) -\int \frac{1}{t}\tan(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$   from here you can easily solve this....

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: If you can easily antidifferentiate $(1/t)\tan t$, then I think we can declare mathematics inconsistent, and find something else to do with our time.

Comment: sorry, I will try to solve it further  ....@Gerry